# gcc 5 does not detect stack smashing for inline functions but gcc 7 does

Tags: gcc, buffer-overflow

This is the code I used to test the stack protection feature of gcc.

```
static inline void  charcpy(char* temp)
{
temp[0]='a';
temp[1]='b';
temp[2]='c';
temp[3]='d';
temp[4]='\0';
}
int main()
{
char temp[3];
charcpy(temp);
return 0;
}
```

When I compile with gcc 7.3 (without specifying any flags), I got the following runtime error on my desktop

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The uname -a command gives the following for my desktop if it matters

```
Linux lixun-Desktop 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

However, when I tried the same thing on a server machine using gcc 5.4, no error shows up. The uname -a command for the server machine is

```
Linux aggravation 4.4.0-137-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 13:14:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Then I use objdump -D a.out to check their assembly codes but still cannot figure out why the stack protection is not working on the server machine.
Here is the output on my desktop (I only paste the section I think might matter)

```
Disassembly of section .init:

0000000000000510 <_init>:
 510:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 514:   48 8b 05 cd 0a 20 00    mov    0x200acd(%rip),%rax        # 200fe8 <__gmon_start__>
 51b:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 51e:   74 02                   je     522 <_init+0x12>
 520:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 522:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 526:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000000530 <.plt>:
 530:   ff 35 8a 0a 20 00       pushq  0x200a8a(%rip)        # 200fc0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 536:   ff 25 8c 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a8c(%rip)        # 200fc8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 53c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>:
 540:   ff 25 8a 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200a8a(%rip)        # 200fd0 <__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4>
 546:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
 54b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   530 <.plt>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

0000000000000550 <__cxa_finalize@plt>:
 550:   ff 25 a2 0a 20 00       jmpq   *0x200aa2(%rip)        # 200ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 556:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
...
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000560 <_start>:
 560:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 562:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
 565:   5e                      pop    %rsi
 566:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
 569:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
 56d:   50                      push   %rax
 56e:   54                      push   %rsp
 56f:   4c 8d 05 ea 01 00 00    lea    0x1ea(%rip),%r8        # 760 <__libc_csu_fini>
 576:   48 8d 0d 73 01 00 00    lea    0x173(%rip),%rcx        # 6f0 <__libc_csu_init>
 57d:   48 8d 3d 24 01 00 00    lea    0x124(%rip),%rdi        # 6a8 <main>
 584:   ff 15 56 0a 20 00       callq  *0x200a56(%rip)        # 200fe0 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 58a:   f4                      hlt    
 58b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
...
000000000000066a <charcpy>:
 66a:   55                      push   %rbp
 66b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 66e:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
 672:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 676:   c6 00 61                movb   $0x61,(%rax)
 679:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 67d:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
 681:   c6 00 62                movb   $0x62,(%rax)
 684:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 688:   48 83 c0 02             add    $0x2,%rax
 68c:   c6 00 63                movb   $0x63,(%rax)
 68f:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 693:   48 83 c0 03             add    $0x3,%rax
 697:   c6 00 64                movb   $0x64,(%rax)
 69a:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 69e:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
 6a2:   c6 00 00                movb   $0x0,(%rax)
 6a5:   90                      nop
 6a6:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 6a7:   c3                      retq   

00000000000006a8 <main>:
 6a8:   55                      push   %rbp
 6a9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6ac:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 6b0:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
 6b7:   00 00 
 6b9:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 6bd:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 6bf:   48 8d 45 f5             lea    -0xb(%rbp),%rax
 6c3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 6c6:   e8 9f ff ff ff          callq  66a <charcpy>
 6cb:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 6d0:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
 6d4:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
 6db:   00 00 
 6dd:   74 05                   je     6e4 <main+0x3c>
 6df:   e8 5c fe ff ff          callq  540 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 6e4:   c9                      leaveq 
 6e5:   c3                      retq   
 6e6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 6ed:   00 00 00
```

And this is the output on the server machine

```
Disassembly of section .init:

00000000004003f0 <_init>:
  4003f0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4003f4:   48 8b 05 fd 0b 20 00    mov    0x200bfd(%rip),%rax        # 600ff8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
  4003fb:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4003fe:   74 05                   je     400405 <_init+0x15>
  400400:   e8 3b 00 00 00          callq  400440 <__libc_start_main@plt+0x10>
  400405:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400409:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400410 <__stack_chk_fail@plt-0x10>:
  400410:   ff 35 f2 0b 20 00       pushq  0x200bf2(%rip)        # 601008 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
  400416:   ff 25 f4 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bf4(%rip)        # 601010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
  40041c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>:
  400420:   ff 25 f2 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bf2(%rip)        # 601018 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
  400426:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
  40042b:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400410 <_init+0x20>

0000000000400430 <__libc_start_main@plt>:
  400430:   ff 25 ea 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bea(%rip)        # 601020 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
  400436:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  40043b:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400410 <_init+0x20>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

0000000000400440 <.plt.got>:
  400440:   ff 25 b2 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200bb2(%rip)        # 600ff8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
  400446:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
...
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400450 <_start>:
  400450:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400452:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400455:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  400456:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400459:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40045d:   50                      push   %rax
  40045e:   54                      push   %rsp
  40045f:   49 c7 c0 40 06 40 00    mov    $0x400640,%r8
  400466:   48 c7 c1 d0 05 40 00    mov    $0x4005d0,%rcx
  40046d:   48 c7 c7 84 05 40 00    mov    $0x400584,%rdi
  400474:   e8 b7 ff ff ff          callq  400430 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  400479:   f4                      hlt    
  40047a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0000000000400546 <charcpy>:
  400546:   55                      push   %rbp
  400547:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40054a:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
  40054e:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400552:   c6 00 61                movb   $0x61,(%rax)
  400555:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400559:   48 83 c0 01             add    $0x1,%rax
  40055d:   c6 00 62                movb   $0x62,(%rax)
  400560:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400564:   48 83 c0 02             add    $0x2,%rax
  400568:   c6 00 63                movb   $0x63,(%rax)
  40056b:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  40056f:   48 83 c0 03             add    $0x3,%rax
  400573:   c6 00 64                movb   $0x64,(%rax)
  400576:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  40057a:   48 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%rax
  40057e:   c6 00 00                movb   $0x0,(%rax)
  400581:   90                      nop
  400582:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  400583:   c3                      retq   

0000000000400584 <main>:
  400584:   55                      push   %rbp
  400585:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400588:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40058c:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  400593:   00 00 
  400595:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  400599:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40059b:   48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  40059f:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4005a2:   e8 9f ff ff ff          callq  400546 <charcpy>
  4005a7:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005ac:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
  4005b0:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
  4005b7:   00 00 
  4005b9:   74 05                   je     4005c0 <main+0x3c>
  4005bb:   e8 60 fe ff ff          callq  400420 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  4005c0:   c9                      leaveq 
  4005c1:   c3                      retq   
  4005c2:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  4005c9:   00 00 00 
  4005cc:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
...
```

I also tried to specify -fstack-protector(-all or -strong) on the server machine, it still shows no error.
Anyone knows why there is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server machine places the array `temp` into a different place in the `main` stack frame.  It uses this operation to compute the address, with a 16-byte offset from the frame pointer:

```
  40059b:   48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
```

The other machine uses this instead:

```
     6bf:   48 8d 45 f5             lea    -0xb(%rbp),%rax
```

There is only an 11-byte offset from the frame pointer.  The canary is stored at offset 8 in both cases.

As a result, on the server machine, there are 5 unused bytes after the array, and the overflow spills into that.  The canary is not overwritten, which is why the overflow is not detected.  But neither is the return address, so it is not possible to redirect execution here.

In real-world software, this would be a source-level stack-based buffer overflow which is not exploitable by accident in the compiled binary.  Such things happen occasionally.

Comment: How do you know the server machine places the temp array into a different place compared to my desktop? Is this caused by the compiler? Or something else?

Comment: So on the server machine, temp start at %rbp-16 and goes to %rbp-15, %rbp-14, ... %rbp-12 and the canary (at %rbp-8) is not overwritten. However, on my desktop, the temp array starts at %rbp-11, then goes to %rbp-10, %rbp-9. When it tries to write %rbp-8, the canary is overwritten so that the stack smashing is detected. Right? Then it seems to be the compiler difference and do you know why gcc 5 put the array at `%rbp-16` while gcc 7 put it at `%rbp-11`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Even with GCC 5, it only happens if you build without `-O2`, at `-O2` (with a compiler barrier to prevent everything from being optimized away) I get an address at offset 11 as well (with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, admittedly). With the default `-fomit-frame-pointer`, your example still doesn't produce an overflow, but I think that is in accident. Moving the array away from the canary is a reasonable enhancement; I will file a GCC bug.